Drag-n-drop crash on WinUi3
I'm developing WinUI3 app and trying to implement drag-n-drop for reordering list items, but app keeps crashing
I'm using ListView element for that
<ListView x:Name="AccountSelector"
          SelectionMode="None"
          Height="Auto"
          CornerRadius="8"
          Padding="-16,-4,-16,-4"
          CanDragItems="True" 
          CanReorderItems="True" 
          AllowDrop="True"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind model.DisplayAccounts}">

Here is what happens when i try to reorder items
Project repository (Reorder crash branch for this bug)
https://github.com/JumperOnJava/11PasswordManager/tree/Reorder-crash
(File with list view code: AccountsListPage.xaml)
I've searched for this issue in the internet but found almost nothing except gh issue that was closed and fixed (i guess use newer version of win app sdk)
I've tried to use this sample's code with some changes but it still crashes
C# debugger doesn't help, application is crashing and not showing any c# exception
Someone on c# discord suggested to attach native debugger and i got this error
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC1D03EFDC (Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll) in WinUi3Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
Error info 1
Error info 2

I can reproduce with your code. Seems like a bug in WinUI3 to me (debugging with WinDBG shows a crash in drag & drop WinUI3 code Microsoft_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::RaiseDragDropEventAsyncOperation::OnStart+0xcc: 00007ffc'76bfefdc 488b03          mov     rax,qword ptr [rbx] s:00000000'00000000=????????????????), you should report to Microsoft

I've managed to find what caused that crash: My application output type was set to Console Application as I was using it for debug reasons.
After setting it to Windows Application my app stopped crashing on drag-n-drop


That's still a bug in Microsoft's code.
